# Extended Kalman Filter - error in update step

Tags: matlab, prediction, robotics, kalman-filter, atan2

I have to implement EKF without actually having good mathematical understanding of it. (Great... not...) So far I have been doing well but since I tried to implement the prediction step things started going wrong.

1. The agent that uses EKF (red) shoots off in a random direction
2. Eventually some variables (pose, Sigma, S, K) become NaNs and the simulation fails

[image]

I base my code on the code from Thrun's "Probabilistic Robotics" on page. 204. This is the part of the code that seems to be messing things up

```
% Get variables
[x,y,th] = getPose(mu_bar);
numoffeatures = size(map,2);

for f = 1:numoffeatures
    j = c(f);
    [fx,fy] = getFeatures(map,f);

    q = (fx-x).^2 + (fy-y).^2;  

    z_hat = [sqrt(q);
             atan2(fy-y,fx-x)-th;
             j];

    H = [(-fx-x)/sqrt(q) (-fy-y)/sqrt(q) 0;
          (fy-y)/q       (-fx-x)/q      -1;
                0               0        0];

    S = H*Sigma_bar*H'+Q;
    K = Sigma_bar*H'/inv(S);

    mu_bar    = mu_bar+K*(z(:,j)-z_hat);
    Sigma_bar = (eye(3)-K*H)*Sigma_bar; 
end
```

I am totally clueless... Any ideas and hints will be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The reason of the agent shooting off is the 'error' when computing the difference between two angles. Those are computed using atan2. Although I know what the problem is I still can't figure out how to fix it.

Let's imagine that after computing atan2 for two objects I have values resulting in a = 135 and b = 45. I computed the difference between them for both possibilities 90 degrees and 270 degrees but the agent still doesn't behave the way it is supposed to. I've never really encountered atan2 before. Is my understanding of calculating the difference between atan2 values wrong? Here is the illustration of my understanding:

[image]

Comment: What is your "q" value when the variables become NaN?  H has a divide by q and sqrt(q), which could be 0.

Comment: At some point "q" becomes Inf... After that variables become NaNs. I can't see why it becomes Inf though.

Comment: Check the parameters in the definition of q.  What is fx, fy, x, y, etc. I can't run this code, so I can't debug.

Comment: fx,fy are <x,y> coordinates of a feature and x,y are <x,y> coordinates of where the agent thinks it is. q is calculating the Euclidean distance from the agent to the object (green star in the image). I am trying to debug but it's very time consuming. Setting conditional points, e.g. q == Inf doesn't work.

Comment: q is the euclidean distance -> if q = Inf, then one of the parameters fx,fy,x,y is also Inf.  Which one?

Comment: No other variable is Inf but there are a few which seem to be very large/small, e.g. -2.7040e+277; 7.5988e+274. The variables that go crazy are: Sigma, Sigma_bar, mu, mu_bar, th, x, y. The values of those are all dependent from each other and they get updates in in that "update" stage. Sigma_bar is actually small even to begin with, e.g. 1.4733e-04 but when ignoring the whole update stage it doesn't seem to behave weirdly. I will paste my entire algorithm for EKF

Comment: The error definitely happens somewhere in the update stage. It is very strange... Up until H variable I am sure things are going fine - q and z_hat are similar to what a non-EKF agent is doing. After that H, S and K are calculated. I think things go wrong then because the consequent state update is very off to what it should be. Tbc...

Comment: I don't know what range of values is considered to be ok for H,S and K so I don't really know what to do as I have no comparison. When calculating K each of variables seems reasonable but after calculating the K and updating the pose the result for e.g. x coordinate was off by a whooping 500 units :/

Comment: @Vetaxili:  There are a lot of algorithms that a programmer can implement without a deep understanding of how they work.  The EKF is just not one of those algorithms:   You really need to understand it to use it effectively.  The best tip I can give you is that while you are focused on the state (x,y) the important part of the EKF is the *noise* represented in Sigma, VMV', Q, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Q` is the process noise?
You cannot set the process noise as

```
Q = randn*eye(3);
```

because you may have negative covariance, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest that I don't actually know what to set Q to and I don't understand what the book says... I thought that because it is supposed to be noise with zero-mean therefore randn was a good choice.

Comment: Q is the covariance of the process noise, it has to be positive matrix. You can set it to eye(3) just to try if this is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Vetaxili:  The *noise* is zero-mean, with variance given by `Q`.  The *noise* is a random process.  `Q` is a description of it.